# Can't run bundle install: Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler"

Tags: macos, rubygems, macos-catalina

I'm trying to run bundle install, but I keep getting this error:

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":

```
  In Gemfile:
    bundler (~> 2.1.4)

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (2.2.29)

Your bundle requires a different version of Bundler than the one you're running.
Install the necessary version with `gem install bundler:2.1.4` and rerun bundler
using `bundle _2.1.4_ install`
```

Tried an update and cleanup. Nothing has worked. Had tons of issues like this ever since updating to Catalina.